# Guava Collections2.transform not work

Tags: java, guava

I launch the code below in debugger:

```
List<MyBean> target = getMyBeans();
Collections2.transform(target, new Function<MyBean, MyBean>() { //BREAKPOINT: target.length equals 4
     @Nullable
     @Override
     public MyBean apply(@Nullable MyBean bean) {
          return removeUnnecessaryProperties(bean); //BREAKPOINT: never invoked
     }
});
```

**Problem:** `Collections2.transform` is never invoked despite `target` has 4 elements.

**Question:** Why `Collections2.transform` is never invoked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`transform` returns a new `Collection` that transforms elements in the underlying collection only as needed. So your `Function` will be invoked once for each element in `target` as you iterate the returned `Collection`, for example.

Judging by your code, what you really want to be doing is much simpler (assuming `removeUnnecessaryProperties` returns the same object that's passed to it):

```
for (MyBean bean : target) {
  removeUnnecessaryProperties(bean);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Collections2.transform` is a lazy operation.

The documentation says:

> The returned collection is a live view of fromCollection; changes to
>   one affect the other.

For that to work, each element must be transformed when it's accessed.

Try using the transformed collection, e.g. iterate through it - then you'll see your transformation method invoked.